# Meteor Collection eliminate duplicates

Tags: javascript, meteor, underscore.js

I have a collection of movies that sit under categories, but I have a view that is suppose to show them all.

When I'm showing all, I have a few duplicates because these movies are in multiple categories.

I am trying to use this code in the helper (client side).

I've found this code that gets me all the titles without duplicates:

```
var distinctMovies = _.uniq(Movies.find({}, {
    sort: {"title": 1},
}).fetch().map(function(x) {
    return x.title;
}), true);
```

This seems to work in removing the duplications because I get an array of 241 titles instead of 251.
However, I want an array with whole objects, instead of an array with only the titles, but when I switch `x.title` per `x` I get the same 251 items.

I am trying to change this code to get the whole movie object and also trying not to run additional loops.

How to achieve this?

Comment: I am realising now I should change the matching with `id` and not `title`, but still doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`_.uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/) documentation:

> If you want to compute unique items based on a transformation, pass an **iteratee** function.

Do this:

```
_.uniq(Movies.find({}, { sort: { title: 1 } }).fetch(), function (movie) {
    return movie.title;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
Template.theater_list.theater=function(){
var cities = _.uniq(Theater.find({}, {sort: {city:1}, fields: {city:true}}).fetch().map(function(x) {
return x.city
}),true);


    return cities;
```